# How to find the solution of non homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving attached question but it is not equal so its further solution is possible.
[Question](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0RHyHmdRczRZXB1TWJwVlJqZHM)

Comment: Do you know the method of undetermined coefficients used to solve certain types (including yours) inhomogeneous linear differential equations?

Comment: Yes I know but it is not prove means both sides are not equal

Comment: You have an error in your $y_p(x)$. It should be $y_p(x) = 2
 e^x+ 3 x+2$.

Comment: The answer below is very good. He also showed the correct $y_p$ and deserves credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You equation is:
$$8y''-6y'+y=6e^x+3x-16$$

1. The corresponding homogeneous linear differential equation:
   $$8y''-6y'+y=0$$
   Its solution (do you know how to solve this equation?):
   $$y^*=C_1e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+C_2e^{\frac{1}{4}x}$$
2. Now we seek a special solution of the following inhomogeneous equation
   $$8y''-6y'+y=6e^x$$
   The form of this special solution is $y_1=Ae^x$ (Do you know why this particular form?), where $A$ is the undetermined coefficient we need to find.
   We calculate $y_1'=Ae^x$ and $y_1''=Ae^x$. Plug in these into the inhomogeneous equation:
   $$8Ae^x-6Ae^x+Ae^x=6e^x$$
   By cancelling exponents on both sides we get:
   $$A=2$$
   Hence $y_1=2e^x$
3. Now lets find a special solution on this equation:
   $$8y''-6y'+y=3x-16$$
   The form of this special solution is $y_2=Ax+B$ (again, do you know why this particular form?), where $A$ and $B$ are again are undetermined coefficients we need to find. 
   They are equal to $A=3$, $B=2$ (can you find the on your own?). Thus, $y_2=3x+2$
4. The general solution of the intial inhomogeneous differential equation is 
   $$y=y^*+y_1+y_2=C_1e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+C_2e^{\frac{1}{4}x}+2e^x+3x+2$$

Comment: My question is we want to prove that the given Yp is a solution of given differential equation ?